# My Labels aren't updating from Form2

Tags: c#, winforms

I've made the following two controls public (Modifiers) on Form1

```
ProgressBar
Label
```

Also on Form1, I launch Form2 like this

```
Form2 f = new Form2(progressBar1, label1)
```

On Form2, I run the following code in Form2

```
 private ProgressBar progressBarForm2;
 private Label labelForm2;

 public Form2(ProgressBar pb, Label lb)
 {
      labelForm2 = lb;
      progressBarForm2 = pb;
 }
```

Then in a method inside Form2.cs, I have the following code

```
 scoreScreen = 4;
 progressBarForm2.Value = scoreScreen;                    
 labelForm2.Text = ((progressBarForm2.Value / progressBarForm2.Maximum) * 100).ToString() + "% Complete";
 labelForm2.Refresh();
 Application.DoEvents();
```

ProgressBar is updating fine on Form1

The progressBar on the Form1 is updating. The label isn't

I assume that when I pass a control into a method, that it's passed by reference so any changes to the control in the method will update the original one.

I can't find a better way to update the control on Form1 so if you guys have a better way, I'm  open.

Comment: I think `(progressBarForm2.Value / progressBarForm2.Maximum)` will return an integer, not a floating point. Cast `progressBarForm2.Maximum` to a float or double.

Comment: this is in general very bad design to share control instances from 1 form to another like that. can you simply have a public method in your form like setProgress where you take the progress number and label text as parameters and then only the form itself will know which control to use to assign the parameter values? that way you will keep things neat and no other form will know internal details of the other form, which is a way more OO approach and nice design usually.

Comment: The code is nonsense, you are using a variable named *progressBar* instead of *progressBarForm2*.  You can't get help if the code doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like *integer divison* case:

```
  ((progressBarForm2.Value / progressBarForm2.Maximum) * 100).ToString()
```

since `progressBarForm2.Maximum` bigger than `progressBarForm2.Value` you have

```
  progressBarForm2.Value / progressBarForm2.Maximum == 0
```

to amend, just *change the order* (first *multiply* by 100 then *divide*):

```
  labelForm2.Text = ((progressBarForm2.Value * 100) / progressBarForm2.Maximum).ToString();
```

Comment: That was a typo in StackOverFlow.

Comment: It was the math causing the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Just be careful is your `ProgressBar.Value` property is ever likely to be as high as 21474837.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your comment "*I can't find a better way to update the control on Form1 so if you guys have a better way, I'm open.*"

It would be better if you leave your controls private to Form1 and expose either methods or properties to access the fields you are interested in.

For example, in Form1

```
public String LabelText
{
     get { return label1.Text; }
     set { label1.Text = value; }
}
```

Then you can pass Form1 instance to the Form2 constructor

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2(this);
```

In Form2

```
 private Form1 parent;


 public Form2(Form1 frm1)
 {
     parent = frm1;
 }
```

Then you can use the public property

```
parent.LabelText = "New Label";
```

You can then do something similar with your ProgressBar